# Problema com meu client utilizando jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, front-end

Eu estou com um problema bem incomum e estranho... Estou utilizando a biblioteca Jquery, porém, a mesma não esta sendo interpretada de forma correta, o problema não esta no código em si, ie, quando eu faço o código mesmo sem erro de sintaxe ou semântica o código não é disparado, porém, quando eu coloco o mesmo código no Codepen funciona de forma correta.

**Nenhum código está funcionando**

eu ja tentei:

```
<!-- Baixar a biblioteca -->

<!-- HTML -->
<div class="col">
  <div id="pallete1" style="width: auto;height: 195px;background-color: 
   #316E1F"></div>
</div>

<script src="tmp.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

/*
 * tmp.js
 */

 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#pallete1").click(function(){
     $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
   });
 });

<!-- Via CDN -->

<!-- HTML -->
<div class="col">
  <div id="pallete1" style="width: auto;height: 195px;background-color: 
   #316E1F"></div>
</div>

<script src="tmp.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" 
integrity="sha384- 
q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

/*
 * tmp.js
 */

 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#pallete1").click(function(){
     $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
   });
 });

<!-- Arquivo unico -->

<!-- HTML -->
<div class="col">
  <div id="pallete1" style="width: auto;height: 195px;background-color: 
   #316E1F"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#pallete1").click(function(){
      $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
    });
  });

</script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" 
integrity="sha384- 
q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Ressaltando que testei no navegadores Edge, Firefox e Chrome e não funcionou, testei também com um servidor e abrindo um arquivo direto do navegador e em outro computador aqui na empresa em que trabalho!

Alguns detalhes importantes:

- O mesmo código funciona no Codepen
- Funcionalidades que exigem Javascript do Bootstrap funcionam, menos os elementos Tooltips e Popovers
- As vezes o código engatilha, mas, para e volta quando quer
- A mesma logica só funciona com VanillaJs

[Link do código para o Codepen](https://codepen.io/fehnolasco/pen/Nappgm?editors=1111)

**Oque eu preciso:**

Eu preciso codar em Jquery e utilizar as funcionalidades do Bootstrap e consigo, porém, só com utilização do Codepen mas eu quero salvar e testar meus códigos no pc

Obrigado a todos

Comment: Tente inverter a ordem de inclusão do jquery e do tmp. Se tmp depende do jquery, ele deve ser incluído depois.

Comment: E se você usar o "width=100%"? Será que a DIV não está ficando sem largura, impedindo o evento click? Só uma hipótese...

Comment: @bfavaretto logo que eu li a pergunta dele eu pensei a mesma coisa que vc e tomei a liberdade para dar uma resposta. Se vc quiser responde-lo diretamente me fala que eu removo o minha resposta ok. []´s

Answer (score 1):

Acontece exatamente como o @bfavaretto falou.

Se a `função` depende do `jQuery` para executar ***ela tem que vir após*** a indexação do mesmo. **Então primeiro vc chama o jQuery e depois a função que depende dele.**

Veja abaixo o exemplo funcionando com o seu código:

```html
<div class="col">
<div id="pallete1" style="width: auto;height: 195px;background-color: 
    #316E1F"></div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" 
      integrity="sha384- 
      q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" 
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#pallete1").click(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
    });
});
</script>
```

**OBS:** O mesmo vale para arquivos `.css`, se vc tem um CSS que depende do Bootstrap ou se vc quer sobrescrever alguma classe dele por exemplo, primeiro deve vir a indexação do `Bootstrap` e apenas depois dele deve vir o seu arquivo `.css` ou então as classes do Bootstrap podem sobrescrever as suas. Então o correto seria fazer dessa forma por exemplo:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="meu-css-que-depende-do-bootstrap.css" />
```